# Python urllib/lib2 error checking & converting between 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python, urllib

The following code works fine most of the time unless the internet connection gets bogged down and then it kills the program and doesn't finish off the complete program.  How do I go about doing the error checking so I can go up and have it rerun the html link again?  Also I'm looking to simplify my entire computer and get everything dumbed down as much as possible.  I only want to be using python 3.4 instead of 2.7 and 3.4.  Right now depending on the program I'm running at the time sometimes I have to use 2.7 and other times 3.4.  I'm not sure but I thought with 3.4 I had to use urllib2 which doesn't have the urlretrieve command if I remember correctly...been 1.5-2 years since I have did any programming at all so I can't remember all the hoops that I was trying to jump through back then but I do remember something like that was coming up.  What do I have to do to convert the program over to 3.4 and get it to work correctly including the error checking/retrying the same link again.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import urllib
import os
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("aimages")
root.geometry("200x200")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

os.chdir('/home/me/images/')
Fileval = open('NextVal.txt','r')
Fileupdate = Fileval.read()
Fileval.close()
Fileupdate = int(Fileupdate)
Filewrite = Fileupdate+10000
Filewrite = str(Filewrite)
FileVal2 = open('NextVal.txt','w')
FileVal2.write(Filewrite)
FileVal2.close()
Filect = int(Fileupdate/10000)
Filect2 = str(Filect)+"9999"
Filecount = int(Filect2)
Fileupdate2 = Fileupdate
while Fileupdate <= Filecount:
    root.title(Fileupdate)
    url = 'http://www.website.com/images/'+str(Fileupdate)+'.png'
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,str(Fileupdate)+'.png')
    statinfo = os.stat(str(Fileupdate)+'.png')
    if statinfo.st_size<10000: 
        os.remove(str(Fileupdate)+'.png')

    Fileupdate = Fileupdate+1
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your primary question about error handling, which I do not entirely address in this answer, can you be more specific about "go up and have it rerun the html link again?" I'm not exactly sure how you intend to handle the error: do you intend to start the whole process over or pick up a the last successful url retrieval, or something else?

In the meantime:

Python 3.4 does have a urlretrieve though it may be deprecated in the future according the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request). Try using:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, str(Fileupdate) + '.png')
```

From my experience, depending on exactly what you are trying to do, I would also try using:

```
urllib.request.urlopen()
```

Some side notes:

I would not recommend naming variables with capital letters. Capitalization is generally reserved for Class names and GLOBAL_VARAIBLES in python. Also snake_case is generally preferred to camelCase in python.

Also I do NOT recommend removing python 2.7. You may not need/want it anymore, but many applications still use or require it. Removing it will cause you far more trouble and headaches than its worth for "simplifying your computer."

Comment: I was more so talking about getting rid of the Idle for Python 2.7 which I believe I could get away with, correct me if I'm wrong.  As for the main topic what I'm looking to do is to have it rerun the same link again...go back and retry the same address again so it should continue on from there if it doesn't find anything or download the image and then still continue on.  Right now if the program can't access the link(internet connection too bogged down or something of that nature) it toally closes out the program altogether and doesn't finish running clear through the end of the routine.